# Querying CKAN in Python using ckanapi

Tags: ckan, python

I used to query with ckanclient thusly:

```
import ckanclient
ckan = ckanclient.CkanClient('http://catalog.data.gov/api/3')
search_params = {                                           
    'q': 'tags:"sea_water_temperature" AND metadata_modified:[2012-06-01T00:00:00.000Z TO NOW]',  
    'fq': 'res_format:HTML',                                
    'extras': {"ext_bbox":"-71.5,41.,-63,46.0"},                   
    'rows': 3                                                     
}
d = ckan.action('package_search', **search_params) 
print d['count']search_params = {                                           
    'q': 'tags:"sea_water_temperature" AND metadata_modified:[2012-06-01T00:00:00.000Z TO NOW]',  
    'fq': 'res_format:HTML',                                
    'extras': {"ext_bbox":"-71.5,41.,-63,46.0"},                   
    'rows': 3                                                     
}
d = ckan.action('package_search', **search_params) 
print d['count']
```

How would I do the same with `ckanapi`?

This doesn't work:

```
import ckanapi
ckan = ckanapi.RemoteCKAN('https://data.noaa.gov/api/3')
search_params = {                                           
    'q': 'tags:"sea_water_temperature" AND metadata_modified:[2012-06-01T00:00:00.000Z TO NOW]',  
    'fq': 'res_format:HTML',                                
    'extras': {"ext_bbox":"-71.5,41.,-63,46.0"},                   
    'rows': 3                                                     
}
d = ckan.call_action('package_search', data_dict=search_params) 
print d['count']
```

Returns a 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is on line 2 of the "This doesn't work" snippet (the error is including the `/api/3`). It should be, as follows, in full:

```
import ckanapi
ckan = ckanapi.RemoteCKAN('https://data.noaa.gov')
search_params = {                                           
    'q': 'tags:"sea_water_temperature" AND metadata_modified:[2012-06-01T00:00:00.000Z TO NOW]',  
    'fq': 'res_format:HTML',                                
    'extras': {"ext_bbox":"-71.5,41.,-63,46.0"},                   
    'rows': 3                                                     
}
d = ckan.call_action('package_search', data_dict=search_params) 
print d['count']
```

Which prints `29` for me.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the above solution has not worked for me. I tried data.gov catalog and used the same code as below:

import ckanapi
ckan = ckanapi.RemoteCKAN('https://catalog.data.gov')
search_params = {
    'q': 'tags:"sea_water_temperature" AND metadata_modified:[2012-06-01T00:00:00.000Z TO NOW]',
    'fq': 'res_format:HTML',
    'extras': {"ext_bbox":"-71.5,41.,-63,46.0"},
    'rows': 3
}
d = ckan.call_action('package_search', data_dict=search_params) 
print (d['count'])

**prints 212284**

Changing search parameters to something weird that theoritically should fetch zero record, also brings 212284 as an answer.